# Pine: cannot use label.new in strategy?

Tags: pine-script

In my strategy, I would like to display some info on the chart

```
//@version=5
strategy("test", overlay=true, max_labels_count=500)

plot(na)

if barstate.islast
    label.new(bar_index, close, "hello")
```

But nothing appears, as you can see here:

[image]

Any idea ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strategies by default are only calculated on bar close and do not run on the real time bar, thus the label will not appear until the 4hr bar closes. There are ways to override this with `calc_on_every_tick`, but this will effect the behaviour of your strategy.

Cheers and have a great day